# flipclock count up from a particular date

Tags: flipclock

For instance, the given start time is 10/28/2014 08:00:00AM (server time). It will count up and show the hours minutes secs lapsed from the given start time? Is this possible with flipclock?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using and seems to work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var date  = new Date(2014, 11, 09);
  var now   = new Date();
  var diff  = now.getTime()/1000 - date.getTime()/1000;

  clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: false
    });
});
```

Comment: this looks like copy-paste from TPB js file hmmm